# How to move an object with a bound function as member

Tags: c++, move

Let say I am binding a function in a class to this:

```
class SubObject {
  public:
    SubObject(std::function<void()> handler) : handler(handler) { }
  private:
    std::function<void()> _handler;
};

class A {
  public:
    A(): _sub_object(std::bind(&A::wrapper, this)) { }
  private:
    SubObject _sub_object;
    void wrapper() { ... }
```

When I create a move constructor the function passed to the SubObject can not be properly moved since it is bound to this and this is not valid in the moved-to object.

```
A(A&& other) {
  std::swap(other._sub_object, _sub_object)
}
```

Is it possible to move a function that is created with bind and this?

Comment: Once *moved*, the `this` is bound to the wrong object.  I'd call `A` a *non-moveable* user-defined type, and just `=delete` the move constructor and move assignment operator.

Comment: What is the *actual* and *underlying* problem that this code is supposed to solve? Please ask about that directly, as there might be other possible solutions. Your question, as it stands right now, is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: does `SubObject` provide a way to rebind a different `A` after construction? If not, you cannot move `A` in a meaningful way. If yes, it depends on how this can be done

Comment: The SubObject is an object where the function is passed to with a wrapper from class A.  @Someprogrammerdude, i'll rephrase my question.

Comment: As it currently stands, there aren't enough details to fix this. The intricacies of `SubObject` make or break its own movability. For example, can you rebind? Can `SubObject` even be moved?

Comment: With rebind you mean something like _sub_object.set_function(std::bind(&A::wrapper, this)) in the A move constructor? I edited the question with a simple SubObject where you cannot rebind.

Comment: Why do you ever need something like `SubObject `?

Comment: you can pretend to move `_sub_object` by creating a new instance with the right `this` pointer. Whether this makes sense depends on whether `A` actually has any members that can be moved.

Comment: Why do I need something like SubObject? Well I could pass along handler where data is being processes an abstracted on different layer.

Comment: you can create the `std::function<void()>` when needed from a lambda or via `std::bind`. The question is why do you want to store it as member of `A`? (because if you don't there is no issue)

Comment: The lambda has a scope. When this is bound to this then the same problem occurs.

Comment: When you need to pass along a handler, make one on the spot. Why store a bound function in the object itself? This serves no purpose.

Comment: @n.m.  I agree, in this example it does not make sense. One can even use a static method on the class where no this pointer is passed. But what if there are arguments and the function in the object is kind of a wrapper or is working on some internal state. I think Eljay got it right: The pointer cannot be rebound so this will be an immovable object.

Comment: @Stefan In that case you should edit your question to show what actual problem you are failing to solve. Like someone else said, your question as it stands is an XY problem.

Comment: Yes, i know. I am still figuring that out. :-)